# Unirest connection timeout

Tags: nginx, networking, unirest

I'm encountering a network problem and I'm running out of ideas to check. I have this unirest request that I'm trying to send but I keep receiving this reply:

```
<html>
    <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
        <hr><center>nginx/1.13.4</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Along with the error message `connection time out`. This error also happens when I try to run other non-unirest requests so I figured that this is a network issue.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Requested that the IP of the client's web service be added to our network's whitelist
2. Requested that my IP be whitelisted to our UAT server's network, just in case my local computer tries to communicate with it
3. Check on our client side if they do any whitelisting in which they said that they don't
4. Tried to run my code from my home computer wherein my code worked perfectly

Any suggestion(s) is very much welcome and appreciated

EDIT:
Here is my configuration for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name  api.nuvelco.com;

    location /{
        proxy_pass http://api.nuvelco.com/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably nginx has several 'server' configurations, which can differ by IP/hostname/port. And you connect to that differently when it works and when it does not?

In most cases 404 means that there is no resource, or PHP is not configured to handle the url.

Checking out nginx access/error logs can be helpful.

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks

Comment: Problem was found in the nginx.conf file. Thanks for the help.